# SEHException in Azure Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis, pinvoke

I have a C# library, which wraps a native DLL, which in turn refers to various other native DLLs.

I wrote a console app to make sure it works, and all was fine.

I now try calling the library from an ASP.Net app, and get a SEHException, with error code -2147467259. So it appears that some part of the native code throws a structured exception when running in IIS but not when standalone.

I have made sure that all DLLs are correctly copied to the Bin folder. I have run in both IIS Express and normal IIS, and have set IIS to run in 64-bit mode.

Appreciate any pointers on how to debug this.

Comment: You can grab dump files from Azure. In the meantime, Azure Web Apps is not a platform that is 100% compatible with Windows Server with IIS, so your native libraries might not work flawlessly (as they might depend on some specific Windows APIs).

Comment: Good to know - thanks for the info. In this case, I get the errors both within Visual Studio / IIS Express, and also Azure web app. This is what made me think it's to do with the IIS context.